# What happened to Bill?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

I know a guy named Billy Bob Joe, or Bill for short. He's usually very upbeat and cheerful, but something happened recently that changed him completely. He won't talk to anyone about it, or about much of anything at all.

I began searching for clues as to what had happened, but the only thing I found was this paper on his desk, apparently written after the event:
[image: Sheet Music]

So, **What happened to Bill?**

Hint:

> It just occurred to me that Bill has a rare condition called [Synesthesia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synesthesia), where his brain is constantly associating music with colors, *intertwining* the two in his mind.

**Edit:** Apologies, but it appears that the image compression is changing the color values of the notes. For reference, they are supposed to be #EEDD00.

Comment: My guess is that Bill got into some sort of treble

Comment: .... and fell off a clef.

Comment: Could be bill became a dad ?

Comment: @IlCorsaroNero You're on the right track, but there's more information that you're missing.

Comment: I notice that the color in some notes are not correct I m near ?

Comment: if I make anagram I have dead or edge  I take this way because the colours in synesthy are subject not object

Comment: I edit the answer I hope that is correct

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Bill's sad because

> his dog died :(

> The notes on the sheet music are D A D G, and the color of the notes is #eedd00 (thanks for the hint btw) or #ed0 for short (duplicate digits can be shortened in hex color codes). Because Bill has synesthesia mixing notes and colors, we can do the same.

> Mixing D A D G and #ed0 results in DeAdD0G.

Answer (score 0):

> Another possible solution is: bob is the son of Gustav Fechner the father of Synesthesia and with this message Bob try to speak with him. This is beacause the note are D A D G and the final g could  mean Gustav

Answer (score -3):

> Possible solution: the notes on the partiture are: D A D G. Part of this makes the word "dad". The other part, the other note could indicate that day of the week. So: G is the fifth note in the scale but is also the first letter of the father of Synestesya more  the letter of the color E E D D 00 if a mix the letter I have DEAD so Billy 's father is dead

Comment: Why 60? Why Tuesday? What's the connection?

Comment: for the graphema color

Comment: What color? How is that related to a day of the week?